# csv-import-helper extension not listed for installation

Tags: extension, csv

On my CiviCRM site (currently CiviCRM 5.42.1 on Drupal 7.82 & PHP 7.4.24 - I'm trying to get an upgrade process together for this site), the `/admin/extensions` page doesn't seem to list the `csv-import-helper` extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/csv-import-helper).  I see maybe 50 or so extensions listed in the "Add New" tab, but `csv-import-helper` isn't one of them.

The extension looks like it would save us *tons* of work.  How can I figure out what's causing it to not be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reviewed extensions appear there. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/publish/#automated-distribution.

It doesn't mean you shouldn't install it, just that nobody's reviewed it as per the above and you need to install it manually using the download from the https://civicrm.org/extensions/csv-import-helper page.

Sidenote: You're on 5.42, and the latest version of that extension says 5.49, so even if it were visible you wouldn't see that latest version.

Comment: Thanks - one of the reasons I wanted to use the auto-install is that on my site (a Bitnami CiviCRM deploy) I can't actually find the extensions directory!  It uses kind of a weird layout I don't understand yet.  But I'll keep searching.

Comment: If you go to Administer - System Settings - Directories, you'll see something at the bottom for "Extensions Directory". It might be a code, in which case you can click the help icon in the description at the top of the page to pop up a bubble which will tell you what that is (pics at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1311)

Comment: Looks like for me on Bitnami it's `[civicrm.files]/ext/`, which is `/opt/bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/`.